# MapReduce set to give multiple output files but I only get 1 for the first job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, chaining

I have three mappers and three reducers that I would like to run.  You'll notice in the code that job2 requires the output of Job1 as it's input.  When running my code I only get one output file for the first job.  The other two jobs seem to be ignored.  How can I get all three jobs to run?

```
package mapreduce;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.DoubleWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.ControlledJob;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

public class RunMapReduceJob {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new RunMapReduceJob().run(args);
}

public void run(String[] args) throws Exception {

    //job 1
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job1 = Job.getInstance(conf, "hourly");

    job1.setJarByClass(RunMapReduceJob.class);
    job1.setMapperClass(MaxConsumptionMapper.class);
    job1.setReducerClass(MaxConsumptionReducer.class);

    job1.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job1.setOutputValueClass(DoubleWritable.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job1, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job1, new Path(args[1])); //output path 1
    job1.waitForCompletion(true);

    //job 2
    Configuration conf2 = new Configuration();
    Job job2 = Job.getInstance(conf2, "max hourly");

    job2.setJarByClass(RunMapReduceJob.class);
    job2.setMapperClass(MaxConsumptionMapper2.class);
    job2.setReducerClass(MaxConsumptionReducer2.class);

    job2.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job2.setOutputValueClass(DoubleWritable.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job2, new Path(args[1])); //input file is output path 1
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job2, new Path(args[2])); //output path 2
    job2.waitForCompletion(true);

    //job 3
    Configuration conf3 = new Configuration();
    Job job3 = Job.getInstance(conf3, "Avg Daily Consumption");

    job3.setJarByClass(RunMapReduceJob.class);
    job3.setMapperClass(AvgConsumptionMapper.class);
    job3.setReducerClass(AvgComsumptionReducer.class);

    job3.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job3.setOutputValueClass(DoubleWritable.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job3, new Path(args[0])); //original input
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job3, new Path(args[3])); //output path 3
    System.exit(job3.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);


    }

}
```

Comment: Use Spark. There is absolutely no reason to be wrestling with MapReduce in 2021, especially if you want to do something "complex" like multiple operations. Calculating the max and average of a dataset is two method calls in Spark. You can even use the Pandas API in Spark 3.2 https://databricks.com/blog/2021/10/04/pandas-api-on-upcoming-apache-spark-3-2.html.

Comment: Thanks Ben, I am doing this for a class project and it has to be done in MapReduce.

Comment: Fair enough, MapReduce is certainly useful for understanding how data is processed in distributed systems.

Comment: Really minor unrelated point.  You should not be creating objects to throw them away. (new Path)  You should reuse them.  I only mention this as your learning and it' s better to learn the right way.

Comment: This code looks pretty solid.  What happens if you comment out the first & Second job and only run the third?  Does it also only produce one file?

Comment: I changed the code to create a directory for each output in the new Path which resolved the issue